# Getting rid of date filter on BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to get rid of this particular date filter on BQ and have a date column instead (kindly check the red circle to see what I'm talking about)

This data was extracted from Microsoft (Bing) Ads using Supermetrics. Any idea how to tackle this? Let me know if you need more information. Thank you.

[image]

AK

Answer (score 1):

So the string depicted in the red circle is part of the table name i.e. `2021111`.
So to view all the data you will want to create a query that looks at all the tables like, but be careful as datasets can get BIG fast.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `BINGADS_AGE_GENDER_*`
```

If you wanted to only combine a certain date range you could use

```
SELECT * 
FROM `BINGADS_AGE_GENDER_*`
WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN '20211001' and '20211101'
```

If you use this datasource within datastudio you can use the @DS_START_DATE and @DS_END_DATE parameters with the date picker.